# Multiple Text select handles - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, cursor, handle

When I try to select text from my edit texts, multiple (maybe 4 four on each side) text select handles appear instead of one of each type.

What can I do to obtain only one handler for each type (right, left) ?

[Example of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCY4Y.png)

My layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:elevation="10dp">
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editBinary"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editHexadecimal"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editHexadecimal"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textBinary"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:digits="01"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

How I call my edittext :

```
    editBinary=(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.editBinary);
    Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf");
    editBinary.setTypeface(typeface);
```

Comment: Please include a minimal sample to reproduce this issue. Did you use custom drawables? What code do you use in your layout? How do you call it from your code?

Comment: @DavidMedenjak I included my code sample. I used a custom background but I still have the problem when I don't use it. I also added a font but once more, I have the same problem when I don't use it.